# How do I set the value of a dictionary that's on another file from another file?

Tags: python, file

I want to change the value of the dictionary in another file

file1.py

```
a = {"a":"cat"}
```

file2.py

```
a["a"] = "dog"
```

Comment: What have you tried?......

Comment: And your question is not clear

Comment: If the question I linked doesn't help you, please let me know and [edit] your question to clarify the problem.